# parallels 9 - mac 10.9 - windows 8.1 rails server running on mac, how to localhost:3000 from internet explorer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, localhost, windows-8.1, parallels

Parallels 9 with windows 8.1 (and more), Mac 10.9.5

rails 4.2 ruby 2.0.0, development app running on localhost:3000

I want to access app from internet explorer running on windows 8.1 in parallels.
I have read every post on the net and submitted a ticket to parallels: no luck.

bridged network (default adapter), tried windows firewall inbound rules,  opening port 3000 (parallels recommendation, no luck)

ifconfig on mac 192.168.0.1, ipconfig on windows depending on network

anybody able to tell me how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried binding rails server to your ip? rails server -b ip (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server )

Comment: This is perfect! No need to turn firewall in windows off @maxd. `code` ifconfig | grep 192 | awk '{print $2}' in Terminal. Start up rails server -b with that IP address and access it from internet explorer in windows in parallels. Thank you both!

Comment: And no need to change from Shared Network (Parallels) to Bridged Ethernet either. The article https://forum.parallels.com/threads/accessing-localhost.305625/#post-748184 is wrong - at least for mac 10.9.5 - parallels 9 - windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

1. Disable windows firewall (no body know how to configure it :)
2. Run rails application with binding to 0.0.0.0 (`rails s -b 0.0.0.0`)
3. Are you sure exactly that your IP is .1? Check it in Preferences/Network in IP Address label.
4. Check that windows ping your host (`ping 192.168.0.1`).

Try to open 192.168.0.1:3000 in IE.